# Graph DB Store Version 0.A.0

Tags: neo4j

This is a long shot, but is there a way to convert a Store version 0.A.0, or look at the relationships and nodes in that store?

Thanks in advance,
Eddie

Comment: Just laod the store in the adequate version of Neo4j.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that failed as well. The graph may just be corrupt.